# android - getting nullpointerexception for no specific reason

Tags: java, android, exception, nullpointerexception

I am working on an android project and as far as I know, I don't make any specific mistakes in my code that would lead to an exception.

I get these two error lines everytime I run my project, but the rest of my code runs without any issues.

The NullPointerException **doesn't have a concrete occurance location**, which confuses me.

I have already searched for similar issues. A possible solution was adding the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE as uses-permission in my Android Manifest file, but to no avail.

```
2020-02-28 XX:XX:XX.333 14615-14651/com.example.package_name E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.example.package_name
2020-02-28 XX:XX:XX.333 14615-14651/com.example.package_name E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
```

Comment: `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` aren't enough, you have to ask user for permissions if you wan't to write or read data.

Comment: @SkypeDogg Thank you for commenting. As far as I know, I don't write or read data, except for SharedPreferences and using some drawables. I am an Android beginner, I would appreciate your guidance.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: @SkypeDogg What would you like to see?

Comment: Whole activity would be nice, or just this part of code which generates this error.

Comment: @SkypeDogg The issue is that I don't know which line or lines of code generate this error. There is no file or line reference in the error, and I don't have any red error lines in my classes and files. I have no way to know what is causing the error. I hoped someone would recognize the error type and refer me to the right class or use case.

Comment: We're gonna need whole activity then. It's impossible to correct code which we can't see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error was thrown by my OnePlus, on the android emulator there was no error shown

Comment: Interesting, I am debugging on a OnePlus 6. So maybe this is device specific?

Comment: just happened again for me on a OnePlus 6.

Comment: I'm getting this as well on a OnePlus 6T.

Comment: getting this as well on a Nokia 6.1 plus

Answer (score 0):

This incident happened to me also when using a physical device of Xiaomi Mi A2, but with a virtual device, the issue dissapears. That means that your code is fine.