# I got runtime exceptions in my android studio:"Fail to get file list and NullPointerException" after adding MultiDex

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-multidex

I add dependency
 `implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'` 
and defaultconfig 
`multiDexEnabled = true` 
In my app gradle file, now my build apk processed successfully but when I run the application I got error in logcat:

```
2020-03-23 17:17:16.312 13609-13609/? E/example.sahayo: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x28000
2020-03-23 17:17:16.401 13609-13639/? E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.example.sahayog
2020-03-23 17:17:16.402 13609-13639/? E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
2020-03-23 17:17:16.402 13609-13639/? E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.example.sahayog
2020-03-23 17:17:16.402 13609-13639/? E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
2020-03-23 17:17:16.403 13609-13639/? E/Perf: Fail to get file list oat
2020-03-23 17:17:16.403 13609-13639/? E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
```

How do I solve my problem?

this is my app gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sahayog"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

and this is my java file.

```
package com.example.sahayog;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;

import static android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

    //private FusedLocationProviderClient client;


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        Button PanicButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.PanicButton);

        final SharedPreferences result = getSharedPreferences("SAVEDATA", MODE_PRIVATE);

        PanicButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent msgIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0,msgIntent, 0);
                SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                sms.sendTextMessage(result.getString("Mobile_no1","data not found"),null, "hello this is sarthak",pi, null);
                Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Message sent successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                //callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+"108"));
                //startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thnx.. now is it okay?

Comment: Hi, i'm having the same issue, did you find a way to solve it @SarthakPandey?

Comment: I'm working on a Flutter project and see the same thing. Not sure of the Flutter scaffolded project has multidex on or off by default. Are we sure this is about multidex?

Comment: This can be also device specific. Are you using OnePlus phone for debugging? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60450949/android-getting-nullpointerexception-for-no-specific-reason

Comment: Can you share android manifest file