# Why is my application failing to get file list?

Tags: java, directory, nullpointerexception, tensorflow-lite

I'm currently working on an Android application (written in Java) using Google ML and TensorFlow. The application is centered around object detection during a live camera stream using the device camera, and uses a TensorFlow Lite model as a custom library to source file lists from. The TensorFlow Lite model specifically is called `mobilenet_v1_0.75_192_quantized_1_metadata_1.tflite` which I got [here](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/lite-model/mobilenet_v1_0.75_192_quantized/1/metadata/1). My issue is that I ran the application to see if it would print the list size, and the application launches just fine; camera preview works, app doesn't crash. However, I'm only to be met with this error;

#### Logcat:

```
2021-07-30 12:19:33.343 15790-15790/? E/objectdetectio: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2021-07-30 12:19:33.754 15790-15828/com.example.objectdetection E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.example.objectdetection
2021-07-30 12:19:33.754 15790-15828/com.example.objectdetection E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
2021-07-30 12:19:33.754 15790-15828/com.example.objectdetection E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.example.objectdetection
2021-07-30 12:19:33.754 15790-15828/com.example.objectdetection E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
2021-07-30 12:19:33.992 15790-15835/com.example.objectdetection E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.camera.privapp.list"
```

According to my research, some results state that that the file path or root is flawed in some capacity. However, I have the `.tflite` model placed within my asset folder, which leads me to wonder **why** exactly I'm receiving these errors and how I can work on resolving them. My `Log.d("TAG", "onSuccess" + detectedObjects.size());` in my code below is supposed to print the object list size, but is clearly not.

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private class YourAnalyzer implements ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {

        @Override
        @ExperimentalGetImage
        public void analyze(ImageProxy imageProxy) {
            Image mediaImage = imageProxy.getImage();
            if (mediaImage != null) {
                InputImage image =
                        InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, imageProxy.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees());
                //Pass image to an ML Kit Vision API
                //...

                LocalModel localModel =
                        new LocalModel.Builder()
                        .setAssetFilePath("ClassifierModel.tflite")
                        .build();

                CustomObjectDetectorOptions customObjectDetectorOptions =
                        new CustomObjectDetectorOptions.Builder(localModel)
                        .setDetectorMode(CustomObjectDetectorOptions.STREAM_MODE)
                        .enableClassification()
                        .setClassificationConfidenceThreshold(0.5f)
                        .setMaxPerObjectLabelCount(3)
                        .build();

                ObjectDetector objectDetector =
                        ObjectDetection.getClient(customObjectDetectorOptions);

                objectDetector.process(image)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(detectedObjects -> {
                            Log.d("TAG", "onSuccess" + detectedObjects.size());
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(e -> Log.e("TAG", e.getLocalizedMessage()))
                        .addOnCompleteListener(result -> imageProxy.close());
            }
        }
    }

    private ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraProviderFuture;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(() -> {
            try {
                ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();
                bindPreview(cameraProvider);
            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));
    }

    void bindPreview(@NonNull ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider) {

        PreviewView previewView = findViewById(R.id.previewView);
        Preview preview = new Preview.Builder()
                .build();

        CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
                .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
                .build();

        preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.getSurfaceProvider());

        Camera camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner)this, cameraSelector, preview);
    }
}
```

Also, just for clarification, my application name is ObjectDetection, this would be the file path of just how the `.tflite` model is placed within my asset folder; `ObjectDetection > app > src > main > assets > ClassifierModel.tflite`

Comment: According to the other stackoverflow threads, if the given phone is a device named OnePlus, the above messages can be ignored and you can try it with the other devices.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60450949/android-getting-nullpointerexception-for-no-specific-reason

Comment: @JaesungChung The thing is, I'm trying to get to the root of why it won't work in partiuclar. Also, this is the primary device that it's being used on, so there really is no other device.